# Understanding gcc 4.9.2 auto-vectorization output

Tags: c, gcc, auto-vectorization

I am trying to learn gcc auto-vectorization module. After reading documentation from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#vectorizab).

Here is what I tried (debian jessie amd64):

```
$ cat ex1.c
int a[256], b[256], c[256];
foo () {
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<256; i++){
    a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
  }
}
```

And then, I simply run:

```
$ gcc  -x c -Ofast -msse2 -c   -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed ex1.c
ex1.c:5:3: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref b[i_11]
ex1.c:5:3: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref c[i_11]
ex1.c:5:3: note: misalign = 0 bytes of ref a[i_11]
ex1.c:5:3: note: virtual phi. skip.
ex1.c:5:3: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
ex1.c:5:3: note: not ssa-name.
ex1.c:5:3: note: use not simple.
ex1.c:5:3: note: num. args = 4 (not unary/binary/ternary op).
ex1.c:5:3: note: not ssa-name.
ex1.c:5:3: note: use not simple.
ex1.c:2:1: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
ex1.c:6:13: note: not vectorized: no vectype for stmt: vect__4.5_1 = MEM[(int *)vectp_b.3_9];
 scalar_type: vector(4) int
ex1.c:6:13: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
ex1.c:2:1: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
ex1.c:8:1: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
```

As per the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#using), I would have assumed to see a clear line saying something like:

```
ex1.c:5: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
```

but that is not the case. I have used the command line option: `-fopt-info-vec-missed` since the command line option: `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose` is now a no-op, as [per report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58134).

So my question: is how do I read the above output to extract that somehow the loop was actually vectorized ?

In case that help:

```
$ gcc -dumpversion
4.9.2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually digging in gcc online doc, I finally found out that I should use instead: `-fopt-info-vec-optimized` (or maybe `-fopt-info-vec-all`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737371/how-to-find-out-which-optimizations-are-actually-applied-when-using-gcc) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fopt-info):

> `optimized`: 
>       Print information when an optimization is successfully applied. It is up to a pass to decide which information is relevant. For example, the vectorizer passes print the source location of loops which are successfully vectorized.
>
> `missed`:
>       Print information about missed optimizations. Individual passes control which information to include in the output.
>
> `note`:
>       Print verbose information about optimizations, such as certain transformations, more detailed messages about decisions etc.
>
> `all`:
>       Print detailed optimization information. This includes ‘optimized’, ‘missed’, and ‘note’.