# Check if a string has only whitespace characters in C

Tags: c, whitespace, c11

I am implementing a shell in C11, and I want to check if the input has the correct syntax before doing a system call to execute the command. One of the possible inputs that I want to guard against is a string made up of only white-space characters. What is an efficient way to check if a string contains only white spaces, tabs or any other white-space characters?

The solution must be in C11, and preferably using standard libraries. The string read from the command line using `readline()` from `readline.h`, and it is a saved in a char array (`char[]`). So far, the only solution that I've thought of is to loop over the array, and check each individual `char` with `isspace()`. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: A loop and a `switch` statement?

Comment: Sounds like you want `strspn`

Comment: Using `strspn` would save me some typing, but I thought the for-loop is more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So far, the only solution that I've thought of is to loop over the array, and check each individual char with `isspace()`.

That sounds about right!

> Is there a more efficient way?

Not really. You *need* to check each character if you want to be sure only space is present. There *could* be some trick involving bitmasks to detect non-space characters in a faster way ([like `strlen()` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650895/why-does-glibcs-strlen-need-to-be-so-complicated-to-run-quickly) to find a NUL terminator), but I would definitely *not* advise it.

You could make use of [`strspn()` or `strcspn()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) checking the returned value, but that would surely be slower since those functions are meant to work on arbitrary accept/reject strings and need to build lookup tables first, while `isspace()` is optimized for its purpose using a pre-built lookup table, and will most probably also get inlined by the compiler using proper optimization flags. Other than this, [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) of the code seems like the only way to speed things up further. Compile with `-O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorize` (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305830/understanding-gcc-4-9-2-auto-vectorization-output)) and run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 3):

"loop over the array, and check each individual char with `isspace()`" --> Yes go with that.

The time to do that is trivial compared to `readline()`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to provide an alternative solution to your problem: use strtok. It splits a string into substrings based on a specific set of ignored delimiters. With an empty string, you'd just get no tokens at all.

If you need more complicated matching than that for your shell (eg. To do quoted arguments) you're best off writing a small tokenizer/lexer. The strtok method is basically to just look for any of the delimeters you've specified, temporarily replace them with \0, returning the substring up to that point, putting the old character back, and repeating until it reaches the end of the string.

Edit:
As the busybee points out in the comment below, strtok does not put back the character that it replaces with \0. The above paragraph was worded poorly, but my intent was to explain how to implement your own simple tokenizer/lexer if you needed to, not to explain exactly how strtok works down to the smallest detail.

Comment: No, to my knowledge `strtok()` does *not* put back the old character. And the result of it is a pointer to the (current) token.