# g++ O1 is not equal to O0 with all related optimization flags

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I know the title is a bit confusing. Let me clarify my problem with a little background:

My program behaves strangely when I compile it with `-O1` flag vs `-O0` flag in terms of execution time. I know `-O1` flag does many optimizations such as `fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments` (More than 40 according to the man page). To figure out which optimization(s) cause this behavior, I plan to remove flags one at a time then compile and test to see if something changes.

Before doing this experiment, I want to make sure that the program compiled with `-O1` and the program compiled with `-O0` plus all flags which `-O1` enables (Lets call `-O0+`) behave similarly. Actually, I expect both method should produce the same binary file since the same optimization flags are enabled.

Compilation with `O1`

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -fopenmp
SOURCE = a_count_f.cpp
EXEC = run
INC = inc

all: $(EXEC)
.PHONY: all

$(EXEC): $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -O1 -o $(EXEC) -I$(INC) $^
```

Compilation with `O0+`

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -fopenmp
SOURCE = a_count_f.cpp
EXEC = run
INC = inc

OPT_FLAGS = -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -ftree-builtin-call-dce -fdse -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion2 -fif-conversion -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-pure-const -fipa-profile -fipa-reference -fmerge-constants -fmove-loop-invariants -fomit-frame-pointer -freorder-blocks -fshrink-wrap -fshrink-wrap-separate -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-backprop -fssa-phiopt -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-pta -ftree-ter -funit-at-a-time

all: $(EXEC)
.PHONY: all

$(EXEC): $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -O0 $(OPT_FLAGS) -o $(EXEC) -I$(INC) $^
```

However, It turned out `-O1` and `-O0+` give quite different result. Despite of all optimizations differences, `-O0` and `-O0+` give very similar results. (By results, I mean execution time)

I have checked both compilation with `-Q --help=optimizers` and the output confirmed that both enables the same flags.

The next for me is to compare assembly codes. Before doing that, I want to ask it here if anyone has an idea why this happens. I didn't include the source code as it seems the problem is not related to source code. But, I can attach it if needed.

g++ version : `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`

Comment: Define `strangely`, provide MCVE, explain how you timed your program.

Comment: Not all optimizations enabled by `-Ox` flags can be enabled/disabled individually. Not all optimizations enabled by `-Ox` flags are documented.

Comment: When a program behaves differently depending on optimization flags it's very often because it invokes Undefined Behaviour (which is a bug in the program). You should post a [mcve] so we can (maybe) help you find your bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The optimizations flags applied by `-O1` only apply when the optimizer is turned on.  You need to specify `-On` with `n > 0` in order for the optimization flags to actually do anything.

To put it another way, `-O0` doesn't turn on the optimizer, so the optimization flags don't do anything.

---

You can turn off optimzations flags by using the `-fno` form of the flag.  For instance the

```
-fcompare-elim
```

flag is turned on by `-O1` and you can turn it back off using

```
-fno-compare-elim
```

---

Another thing to note, as pointed out by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c), is that [not all optimizations have a flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_-O1_.28-O2.2C-O3.2C_-Os_or_-Og.29_equivalent_to_individual_-foptimization_options.3F) so there isn't any way to turn those particular optimizations off.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Then, how can I enable/disable individual optimizations flags? Right now I have 40+ flags which cause the behavior I am interested in. Any subset of these flags might be the real cause. How can I find them?

Comment: Additionally, [many optimizations enabled by -O1/2/3 have no individual flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_-O1_.28-O2.2C-O3.2C_-Os_or_-Og.29_equivalent_to_individual_-foptimization_options.3F).