# Optimization flag removing undefined reference to extern variable

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, extern

Considering the following piece of code :

```
extern int var;

void foo(int & param)
{
   (void) param;
}

int main(void)
{
   foo(*(&var));
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled this way :

```
$ g++ -Os -o test.o -c test.cpp
$ g++ test.o
```

But when I remove the `-Os` flag, there is an undefined reference to `var`.

What kind of optimization are enabled by `-Os` to skip this undefined reference ? (I tried to replace the flag by all the optimizations it enable according to the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) but I can't reproduce without `-Os`.

Another question, when I compile the sample in one go :

```
$ g++ -c test.c
```

There is no error even though there is no optimization flag, why ?

Comment: `-Os` probably removes all of the code as it does nothing.  You can output an assembly file to check that.

Comment: Also note that just enabling the same flags doesn't actually enable optimization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175916/g-o1-is-not-equal-to-o0-with-all-related-optimization-flags/53175963#53175963

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After performing some binary search on the flags, the relevant one appears to be `-fipa-pure-const`, demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/br68GbKGb). The description is "Discover which functions are pure or constant. Enabled by default at -O1 and higher.", which presumably includes noticing that `foo` doesn't actually do anything with `param`.