# Minimum specific optimization flags required to get the same result as with `-O1` with clang

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

Consider the following example:

```
static int sum(int x)
{
   int s = 0;

   for (j = 1; j <= x; ++j)
       s += j;

   return s;
}

int main() { return sum(10); }
```

When you compile this code in clang using `-O1`, the `sum` function (if it weren't static) is re-implemented by the compiler using the arithmetic progression formula `f(x)=x(x+1)/2` (actually, `g(x)=(x-1)(x-2)/2 +2x-1` that mathematically is the same but healps dealing with overflow issues), and `main` is re-implemented by directly returning 55 (and them `sum` is removed).

**NOTE:** I'm using godbolt for all of my tests, using `x86-64 clang (trunk)`.

All of this, I understand, happens because of the following set of optimization techniques all working together:

1. The compiler performs a scalar evolution analysis of `sum`. It detects that the value of `s` in the `x`-th iteration is `g(x)`, so the computation of `s` is moved outside the loop.
2. Since now the loop is empty, it's removed.
3. Since now the function has shrank in size, it's candidate for inlining, and the `main`'s call to `sum` is replaced by the body of the function.
4. The replaced expression depends solely on a constant, and so the expression is evaluated in compilation-time, giving `55` (and since `sum` is now a static function where no one is calling it, it's removed, probably by the linker I guess).

I would like to know which specific compilation flags (besides any `-Ox`) are related to each one of the four points.

1. Scalar evolution, but I haven't found which `-fsomething` compilation flag enables it.
2. I guess it's related with dead code elimination?
3. Inline analysis. I have tried to implement the program as:

```
inline int sum(int x) { return x*(x-1)/2; }
int main() { return sum(10); }
```

and then activate the flag `-finline` (instead of `-O1`), but `main` keeps calling `sum`, so no inlining is being performed. I would like to know what should I do (which specific compiler flags to activate) to make the body replacement happen.

4. Constant folding? I know that if I implement `main` as:

```
int main()
{
   int const x = 10;
   return x * (x + 1) / 2;
}
```

the constaint folding applies even with `-O0` and no other flag active, but if I remove `const` from `x`, then it doesn't (with `-O1` does). Which flag forces a constant folding even if `x` is not a constant?

I know that this feels as different questions, but it's actually one: what is the minimal set of specific compiler flags required to make the compiler give the same output for the original program as if `-O1` were active?

Comment: Do note that some flags just don't exist and there are some things that `-On` does that can't be toggled on or off: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175916/g-o1-is-not-equal-to-o0-with-all-related-optimization-flags/53175963#53175963

Comment: I'm more curious about the reason behind your question. Is there an underlying problem that knowing this information would help solve? Or is it just plain curiosity? If there's an underlying problem, then please ask about that directly instead. If it's curiosity, then please add a note about that as well.

Comment: Related, how to extract the optimization flags from clang: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71670770/4641116

Comment: if you need values to be calculated compile time then better require that with consteval/constexpr. That will be more visible for anyone maintaining the code than hacking with optimization flags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Let's call it pedagogical research. There isn't any specific problem behind it.