# how to customize c(xx)_flags to simulate O(x) optimization option

Tags: c++, c, gcc

My software is a complex project, when different optimization levels are used, different results are output.Tracing code to find the root cause of the problem wastes a lot of time.

By man gcc, I see:

```
gcc -Q -O3 --help=optimizers
```

In this way, I get the details of the different levels of optimization.
Then, I try to use these compile flags to simulate the optimization level:

```
# use flags instead of -O(x)
# cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O2"
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fassume-phsa -fbranch-count-reg,,,"
# or
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O0 -fassume-phsa -fbranch-count-reg,,,"
```

The final program output is still the result of "O0". Using these compilation flags, it is not equivalent to "O(x).

Can Someone help me?

---

gcc 9.1, here are all the compilation options I used to try to simulate the" O1" option.

> -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O0 -fbranch-count-reg -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdefer-pop -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-profile -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fipa-reference-addressable -fmove-loop-invariants -fomit-frame-pointer -freorder-blocks -fshrink-wrap -fsplit-wide-types -fssa-phiopt -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-builtin-call-dce -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-fre -ftree-pta -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175916/g-o1-is-not-equal-to-o0-with-all-related-optimization-flags

Comment: Did you try the simple stuff already? ASAN, UBSAN, `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`?

Comment: If your code generates different results at different optimization levels, you almost certainly have undefined behaviour somewhere in the code.  If the code is sound, optimization won't change the results — it will just change the speed at which those results are obtained.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html "Not all optimizations are controlled by a flag."  There does not have to be any set of `-f` options that is equivalent to `-O`, `-O2`, `-O3`, etc.  So what you ask is in general not possible.

Comment: thinks to everyone, problem solved. I use "-O2" with "close all O2 flags (like, -fno-tree-sink)". finally i find "-fno-tree-dse" is useful.